# onchange equivalent in angular2

Tags: angular

i'm using onchange to save the value of my input range into firebase , but i have an error who say that my function is not defined.

this is my function

```
saverange(){
  this.Platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.rootRef.child("users").child(this.UserID).child('range').set(this.range)
  })
}
```

this is my html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>Rayon <span favorite><strong> {{range}} km</strong></span></ion-col>
    <ion-col><input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="40" [(ngModel)]="range" onchange="saverange()"></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

what is the equivalent of onchange in angular , if one exist.
thank you

Comment: `(change)`, 5 more to go

Answer (score 217, accepted):

> We can use [Angular event bindings](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#event-binding) to respond to [any DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).
>   The syntax is simple. We surround the DOM event name in parentheses and assign a quoted template statement to it. -- [reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html)

Since `change` is on [the list of standard DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), we can use it:

```
(change)="saverange()"
```

---

In your particular case, since you're using NgModel, you could break up the two-way binding like this instead:

```
[ngModel]="range" (ngModelChange)="saverange($event)"
```

Then

```
saverange(newValue) {
  this.range = newValue;
  this.Platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.rootRef.child("users").child(this.UserID).child('range').set(this.range)
  })
}
```

However, with this approach `saverange()` is called with every keystroke, so you're probably better off using `(change)`.

Comment: Strangely this doesn't work for me for some reason, the function is not fired.....I am not sure why. Looks like in recent version of Angular you have to use (input), for the input element of type text.

Comment: In code I have been asked to maintain but did not write, I see `(onchange)="someValue"` 
Is onChange available in angular on checkboxes, because it appeared to half-ways work.

Answer (score 13):

In Angular you can define `event listeners` like in the example below:

```
<!-- Here you can call public methods from parental component -->
<input (change)="method_name()">
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
<input (input)="saverange()>
```

Answer (score 5):

@Mark Rajcok gave a great solution for ion projects that include a range type input.

In any other case of non ion projects I will suggest this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="points" #points maxlength="8" [(ngModel)]="range" (ngModelChange)="range=saverange($event, points)">
```

**Component:**

```
    onChangeAchievement(eventStr: string, eRef): string {

      //Do something (some manipulations) on input and than return it to be saved:

       //In case you need to force of modifing the Element-Reference value on-focus of input:
       var eventStrToReplace = eventStr.replace(/[^0-9,eE\.\+]+/g, "");
       if (eventStr != eventStrToReplace) {
           eRef.value = eventStrToReplace;
       }

      return this.getNumberOnChange(eventStr);

    }
```

The idea here:

1. Letting the `(ngModelChange)` method to do  the Setter job:

   `(ngModelChange)="range=saverange($event, points)`
2. Enabling direct access to the native Dom element using this call:

   `eRef.value = eventStrToReplace;`