# right way to call a function after selected option. Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I need to call a function after one of the options is selected.

which is the best way to do it? im using angular4.

```js
modo(){
  // if modo 1 is selected do something.
  // if modo 2 is selected do something.
  // if modo 3 is selected do something.
}
```

```html
<label>Modo :</label>
<select id="selectid" class="form-control-mb-12">
   <option value="mod1">MODO 1</option>
   <option value="mod2">MODO 2</option>
   <option value="mod3">MODO 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: (change) = onChange($event). this will work for changing values

Comment: can u expand please?

Comment: it's `(change)` check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366375/onchange-equivalent-in-angular2

Comment: sorry @FabioG typo

Comment: @IxamDeirf you got ur expanded ans

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the change event handler as folows, which passes the selected value to the handler:

```
<select id="selectid" class="form-control-mb-12" (change)="modo($event.target.value)">
   <option value="mod1">MODO 1</option>
   <option value="mod2">MODO 2</option>
   <option value="mod3">MODO 3</option>
</select>

modo(value: string){
  switch(value) {
    case "mod1":
       // if modo 1 is selected do something.
       break;
    case "mod2":
       // if modo 2 is selected do something.
       break;
    case "mod3":
       // if modo 3 is selected do something.
       break;
  }
}
```

You could also bind the value of the select to a property on your model using [(ngModel)] then you wouldn't need to pass the value to the handler as your model would already have it.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: and then how my funcion should be inside? to see which option was selected?

Comment: The value of the option selected will be passed as a string to the modo function. What you do with it then is just javascript, e.g. a switch statement - or whatever you want to do with it. Added example.

Comment: I added how to modify the function, but this isn't really anything to do with angular, just javascript (or in this case TypeScript)

Comment: Great - please mark as answered if this answered your question.

Answer (score 8):

The Angular way to approach this in a dropdown would be to allow Angular to manage the value with `ngModel`, and have Angular watch for the `ngModel` value to change by using `ngModelChange`.

This is how it would look with the example:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="chosenMod" (ngModelChange)="modo()" id="selectid" class="form-control-mb-12">
   <option value="mod1">MODO 1</option>
   <option value="mod2">MODO 2</option>
   <option value="mod3">MODO 3</option>
</select>
```

In your component you would add a variable declaration for the chosen dropdown value, and then reference that in your `modo` method:

```
chosenMod: string = "";

modo(){
  switch(this.chosenMod) {  
     case "mod1": { 
        //do something
        break;
     }
     case "mod2": { 
        //do something
        break;
     }
     case "mod3": { 
        //do something
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

What will happen is because of the two-way binding on `chosenMod`, Angular will be watching for the value to change in the dropdown, and it will update `chosenMod` when the dropdown selection changes.

When you bind to the `ngModelChange` event, Angular will watch for the value of the `ngModel` declaration to change, and it will run the code specified.

The combination of these two tags will mean that as soon as the selection changes, Angular will update the value of `chosenMod`, and then execute the `modo()` method.

Since you've bound to the component variable chosenMod, you don't need to send the value of the selection into the modo method you will be executing.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `ngModel` you can use `ngModelChange`

```
<select ngModel (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)" id="selectid" class="form-control-mb-12">
   <option value="mod1">MODO 1</option>
   <option value="mod2">MODO 2</option>
   <option value="mod3">MODO 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: and then how the doSomething function should be ? to check which optiona has been selected..

Comment: `doSomething(value: string) { console.log(value); }`

Answer (score 2):

In angular 4+ you should write select code  like this

```
  <select [ngModel]="info" (onModelChange)="function()">
      <option [ngValue]="">select</option>
      <option *ngFor="info of infoSelect">{{info}}</option>
    </select>
```

This is the best way to call function on select

Answer (score 0):

**use (selectionChange)** example:

```js
<mat-select [(value)]="value" (selectionChange)="updateCategory()">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name"> name </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```