# Calculation module using 2 way data binding without any click

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-cli, 2-way-object-databinding

I started a new web project for a company and decided to use Angular Cli.

One of their need is to have a calculation module in order to help customers to calcul their potential salary.

So I created a `simulation` component with a simple View ( a form with 3 input).

Here is a part of the `simulation.component.html` with one of my 3 input and the 2 way Data Binding ***which work***. The calcul are over simplified but I'll adjust them later.

```
<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="md-form">
          <input [(ngModel)]= "chiffreAffaire" mdbActive type="number" id="form1" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
          <label for="form1" class="">Chiffre d'affaire Hors tax (Mensuel)</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<p> CA : {{chiffreAffaire}}</p>
<p> RESULT : {{chiffreAffaire*2}}</p>
```

Like you can see I put my calcul directly in my HTML Balise and that can't be a good solution ! In fact if the calcul was that simple it may be ok but I'll need to add some condition in terms of amounts.

***Tell me if it's not the best practice*** but in my opinion, what I need to do  is to add a function in my `simulation.component.ts` which will make the calcul and call it in my `p` balise.

I know that it's possible to call a function with a click on a button but they asked me to make this 100% dynamic, they just want the function to be applied each time the user modify the input.

So I thought about something like that `<p>{{calcul()}}` with a `calcul()` function in my `simulation.component.ts` file

```
import { Component, Input, Output,EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simulation',
  templateUrl: './simulation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simulation.component.scss']
})

export class SimulationComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() chiffreAffaire: number ;

  calcule()
  {
    this.chiffreAffaire = this.chiffreAffaire*2;
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

but it clearly don't work.

Comment: "…don't (doesn't) work…" — [Worst error description ever](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So we should guess the problem & solve it?

Comment: Sorry guys.
I wanted to call a function each time I modified an input. Generally we call a function after a click on a button but my need was a bit different.

Like @tomichel showed me there is an angular directive `(ngModelChange) = "function()` which help to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to add a (change) function to your input or break your ng model up

have a look at this response here:

[onchange equivalent in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366375/onchange-equivalent-in-angular2)

Comment: Thank you , indeed it helped me to solve my problem !

Comment: Glad I could help, please consider accepting the answer as correct.