# Enable button based on input - Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

My button has to enable when I fill my input. Currently it keeps being disabled.

**HTML button:**

```
<button pButton type="button" class="buttonCSS" [disabled]="buttonDisabled" label="Boeken" id="button" (click)="on_Boek()"></button>
```

**HTML input**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="sBoekOmschrijving" (onchange)="on_ChangeInput()" pInputText/>
```

**TypeScript function**

```
on_ChangeInput()
{
 this.buttonDisabled = false 
}
```

**Typescript button disabled always true**

```
buttonDisabled = true
```

Most likely a stupid question.. but I really can't figure it out.. thanks anyway. I am not allowed to use Jquery.

Comment: As it is said here[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366375/onchange-equivalent-in-angular2) try the (ngModelChange) event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `onchange` are for selects, not inputs
- `(onchange)` doesn't exist in Angular (it's `change`)
- `(input)` could do the trick

But the best solution would be :

```
<button pButton type="button" class="buttonCSS" [disabled]="!sBoekOmschrijving" label="Boeken" id="button" (click)="on_Boek()"></button>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="sBoekOmschrijving" pInputText/>
```

By relying on falsy values, you put the condition

> Disable the button if the `sBoekOmschrijving` field has no value

Comment: Thanks for the help, both (input) and [disabled]="!sBoekOmschrijving" did the trick. 

P.S. Our boss used (onchange) in projects, but thansk for your advice being it (change)

Comment: @Undertaked `onchange` is a Javascript binding, If you use Angular and want to bind to your component, you remove the "on" : `onclick → (click)`, `onchange → (change)` ...