# select value number multiply reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to multiply a value of a select mat by another already established, for example `A x B` where `A` is a fixed number does not change and `B` would be a number of a mat-select that does change.

Then the result of that multiplication I want to save it in another field of a reactive form.

So far I have tried this but the result of the multiplication does not change, that is always is `1380` should change if I change in the mat-select:

component.ts

```
precio: 690
selectedPersona = 2;
numeroPersonasTotal: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.forma = this.fb.group ({
    numeroPersonas: [ this.selectedPersona ],
    precioPersona: [ this.precioPersona() ],
    totalPrecio: [ this.totalPrecio()],
  });

  this.numeroPersonasTotal = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];
  console.log(this.precio, this.selectedPersona);
}

totalPrecio() {
  return this.precio * this.selectedPersona;
}

guardarReserva() {
  this.fs.saveReserva(this.forma.value);
  console.log(this.forma.value);
}
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="guardarReserva()" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
      <mat-label>Número de personas</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="selectedPersona" (ngModelChange)="totalPrecio(selectedPersona)" formControlName="numeroPersonas">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let persona of numeroPersonasTotal" [value]="persona">{{persona}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span>Precio por persona</span>
            <span>USD {{precio}}</span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span>Total</span>
            <span>USD {{totalPrecio()}}</span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-3 mt-4">Reservar</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I use for reactive forms when I want to manipulate the values. I'm going to give this my best shot, because your ReactiveForm formatting is a bit confusing.

Create a method call `onChanges()`. Inside this function you will want to subscribe to value changes of the form and pass the data which is the form data to the function that you are using to manipulate the values.

```
onChanges() {
   this.forma.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
      this.totalPrecio(data);
   });
}
```

then we will want to change `totalPrecio()`

```
totalPrecio(data) {
    return this.precio * data.numeroPersonas;
}
```

then finally make sure we call this function in `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.onChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the approach but I get error in the console: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined`

Comment: Oh, when declaring your form change `this.fb.group` to `new FormGroup`

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement `onChanges()` or pass `$event` to `totalPrecio()`.

Implementing onChanges() is the best practice option:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

If you want to stick with the current format, you can pass `$event`.
( Similar to this question: [onchange equivalent in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366375/onchange-equivalent-in-angular2) )

Add a field to hold the total (I chose to name it totalPrecioN):
I also noticed `precio: number = 690` is missing a ';'.

```js
precio: number = 690; // missing ';' above
selectedPersona = 2;
totalPrecioN: number = 0;
```

I've removed  the `mat-` from the form, but this shows how to pass it:

```html
  <form [formGroup]="forma">
        <select [value]="selectedPersona"
                formControlName="numeroPersonas" 
                (ngModelChange)="totalPrecio($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let persona of numeroPersonasTotal" [value]="persona">
            {{ persona }}
          </option>
        </select>


      <div>
        <span>Precio por persona</span>
        <span>USD - {{precio}}</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <span>Total</span>
        <span>USD - {{totalPrecioN}}</span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Next, change totalPrecio to use the value passed in:

```js
  totalPrecio(selectedPersonaN: number) {
    console.log(selectedPersonaN); // if you want to see the value change
    this.totalPrecioN = this.precio * selectedPersonaN;
  }
```

I put a version on StackBlitz showing how to pass $event: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abb2ux

Top is the current version, bottom passes `$event`.
I changed some things around to just show the form.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, did you check the stackblitz? I do not see any implementation

Comment: In the reactive form which parameter should I place in `totalPrecio: [ this.totalPrecio()],`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to save it to a repo and had to remake the project. It should be available now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abb2ux (github repo if you want that: https://github.com/jarhoads/angular-abb2ux)

Comment: `this.totalPrecioN` should work (or whatever you choose to name it).

Comment: While it's true now it works, I can not save that value in reactive form. In other words, if I see the result in the console, when I change the value in `select` it changes the final result but I can not save that value. In other words, `this.totalPrecioN` does not save the value only I get `null` as a result. By the way, your stackblitz is still not working.