# How to auto fill value in one drop down with the same value selected in another dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, angular-material, frontend, angular-ngselect

- I have two dropdowns with same values in both the drop downs.
- Booking Class and Class of service dropdowns in different components.

---

When I select any value from Booking class dropdown, it should be filled in Class of service dropdown and also allow to change the value by clicking the dropdown.
If no value is selected in the Booking Class dropdown, the class of service dropdown can be as it is.

---

[Booking class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsosK.jpg)

[Class of service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNV51.jpg)

After selecting First class from Booking class dropdown,when I go to Class of service dropdown, it should be automatically filled as First class. And on clicking the dropdown, the list should be visible if needed to change.

---

Booking Class

```
<div>
      <label class="col-sm-2">{{'Booking Class' | translate}}</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <ng-select placeholder="Any" [virtualScroll]="true" formControlName="serviceClass">
                              <ng-option *ngFor="let item of bookingClassData[value]="item.classOfServiceName">  {{item.classOfServiceName}}</ng-option>
                            </ng-select>
                      </div>
 </div>
```

---

Class of Service

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>{{'Class Of Service' | translate}}</label>
               <ng-select placeholder="Select Class Of Service" [virtualScroll]="true"    formControlName="classOfService">
                  <ng-option *ngFor="let data of classOfServiceData" [value]="data.classOfServiceName">
                    {{data.classOfServiceName}}</ng-option>
                </ng-select>
    </div>
```

---

I have separate component.html files and respective component.ts files for each.

---

Answer (score 1):

This is an onchange event listener to demonstrate the idea. So to see it in action, you need to change the selection. I accomplish the goal via dictionaries and loops.

```js
//plastic cups can have coffee or tea
//glass cups can have Iced Coffee, Iced Tea, or Soda
//and we don't need to include anything here for no cup selected
cups = {"plastic": ["Coffee", "Tea"], "glass": ["Iced Coffee", "Iced Tea", "Soda"]}

//get the selection box for cups
cup = document.getElementById("Cup");
//add an event listener
cup.addEventListener("change", function() {

  //get the selection box for drinks
  drink = document.getElementById("Drink")
  //set its innerHTML to be nothing
  drink.innerHTML = "";
  //if the value from the cups selection box is not nocup (no cup selected)
  if (cup.value != "nocup")
  {
    //loop over the different drinks
    for(var i = 0; i < cups[cup.value].length; i++)
    {
      //and add them to the drink options drop down
      drink.innerHTML += "<option>" + cups[cup.value][i] + "</option>";
    }
  }
  //otherwise, if the cups selection box is "nocup" (no cup is actually selected)
  else
  {
    //set the drinks selection box back to "No cup selected"
    drink.innerHTML = "<option>No cup selected</option>"
  }

});
```

```html
<select id="Cup">
  <option value="nocup">
    Select one
  </option>
  <option value="plastic">
    Plastic
  </option>
  <option value="glass">
    Glass
  </option>
</select>

<select id="Drink">
  <option>
    No cup selected
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, though it uses plain JS rather than ng-select (custom Angular Library), and while it moreso changes the fact from selecting an existing option to filling in the options, the concept is the same. That being said: Rather than explicitly adding a listener via jsScript, @ClarkeGriffin, you can use [`(change)`](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#outputs) to add a function to `Booking` that reads when the selection is changed, at which point you use jQuery to select the right option from `Service`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add (change).And  I have separate component.ts files for this. If I give the function in Booking ts file, how can we link it to the Service ? Can you provide code based on my snippet? @fabc

Comment: @ClarkeG Hmm... frankly, I'd normally go about this by including a bridging component.ts file for Booking.ts and Service.ts that imports them and only includes the function (seeing as both are needed for this and won't likely be called when only one of them is on screen, as I understand it). I believe I'm misunderstanding the question you're asking, would you kindly elaborate? (tried to start a chat, realized I can only do that in my own answers, sorry about that. Or I've forgotten how to do it properly)

Comment: Even I am unable to create the chat. My doubt is where do we define the function (change)? @fabc

Comment: @ClarkeG oh, it's not something you have to define, it's like editableSearchTerm, it's part of ng-select. Unless you mean where to define the function that you will be using in (change) `(change)="yourFuncName($event)"`, an example of this in base angular can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366375/onchange-equivalent-in-angular2), in which case I'd recommend a bridge like I said in my previous comment: new component.ts file, for this. Make sure to document it for future use/review.

Comment: Yes, I was asking where to define the function . Also,can you share the logic based on my code? Sorry, I am just a beginner.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble explaining myself here: You said you had separate `component.ts` files for each (one for `Booking` and one for `Service`). My suggestion was to create a third `component.ts` file that bridges these two classes (components). You can import said `Booking` and `Service` into the bridging component, allowing you to reference both. I was suggesting using jQuery though, to find the element in the page rather than unifying the components. Shaner's answer uses default DOM exploration, the change would be: `$(#ng-selectServiceID)` and then select the option you want selected.

Comment: @fabc, I totally understand your point. Can we do this without using a bridge ts file as Iam not allowed to create new files? It would be helpful if you can give your approach as an answer.

Comment: You could create it inside `Booking` itself, but it would be a little odd to have such a specific case's function defined in a singular component. You could include this function inside of a `<script>` tag but I don't believe Angular would recognize it if it's not in an external `script.js` file... If it does, you'd have to rely on Shaner's excellent answer, the only change being that his first snippet would be inside of `<script>/*Shaner's JS function, without listener*/</script>`, and the `(change)` would reference this function. I'm not sure that would work. Otherwise you'll have to use JS

Comment: @fabc I haven't learned angular yet - all I know is that it is a slightly more powerful than the usual templating system. Since it was marked with a javascript category tag, I took a stab at it. If you have a more "angular"ic method, I'd be happy to upvote your answer.

Comment: @ShanerM13 , your response ended up being the better one, the more "angular"ic method would require creating new files, which the OP confirmed they couldn't use... I'd upvote your answer, but you can only do that once